# Plus and Minus buttons in React which call the same function?

Tags: reactjs

I have Add and Remove buttons in my project. To keep my code organised Im attempting to call the same function with both of them, and use the refs to see which one was clicked:

```
  addOrRemoveSet(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.addOrRemoveSetTest === 'remove') {
      // do something
    } else {
      // do something else 
    }

  }

    <form onSubmit={this.addOrRemoveSet}>
      <button
        ref={() => this.addOrRemoveSetTest = 'remove'}
      >Remove
      </button>
      <button
        ref={() => this.addOrRemoveSetTest = 'add'}
      >Add
      </button>
    </form>
```

addOrRemoveSetTest always equals 'add'. Im assuming both ref functions run on submit? This must be a common problem to solve so is there a solution which is considered best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and it always be, this is how code flows:

```
// first this will be executed
ref={() => this.addOrRemoveSetTest = 'remove'} 

// then this , so the value will always stay add
ref={() => this.addOrRemoveSetTest = 'add'}
```

---

Your code should be like :

```
onClick = {() => this.addOrRemoveSetTest = 'remove'}
// AND
onClick = {() => this.addOrRemoveSetTest = 'add'}
```

Here is the link to the working example :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-add-remove-single

Answer (score 1):

for what it's worth, why would you use ref to switch functionalities inside the function, why don't you use name attribute inside `button` tag so you code becomes something like:

```
    addOrRemoveSet(e) {
const name = e.target.name;
e.preventDefault();
if (name === 'remove') {
// do something
} else {
// do something else 
}
}

<form onSubmit={this.addOrRemoveSet}>
  <button
    name='remove'
    onClick={this.addOrRemoveSet} //check here
  >Remove
  </button>
  <button
    name='add'
    onClick={this.addOrRemoveSet} //check here
  >Add
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Im logging out e.target.name and its empty.

Comment: please check the edit, you should add onClick for buttons